# How to display module ouptput in a page with content

Tags: google-maps

I would like to display my module otuput in one page. The only solution I found till now is to use iframes. Is there some better solution?

I created a module to display a map with branches, branches are stored in DB. But before and after this map there should be some content, like text or pictures.

I hope there is a posibility. Maybe with blocks?

Comment: did you try to use hook_menu and make a new page that display your map (if you want to make it custom) and if you can make a block using a view you can put it at any new page

Comment: I allready use hoock_menu and it's on a page with own link. But my concern is to have a possibility to put it on some page with content, where admin without html or php konweledge can change text throw edit button.

Comment: maybe there a way to enable php in content? so I can symple write <?php print module_function(); ?> in the content?

Comment: That's it, I simply printed the output of my module with php, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the code for output your result is not so big than you can put the code in block and show that block on any page you want.

Comment: Hi, Sumit, thank you for the answer. I have to display this map only on one single page, and there are queries to the remote DB, so I would like this block to be called only on this single page. Maybe there are some possibilities like print the output of the module in the middle of content? Or print the output somthere in template?

Comment: You can print the block as
`$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 'block_id');

$output .= $block['subject'];

$output .= $block['content'];

print $output;`